# searching for right hosting site for material design

Tags: hosting

I am just beginner in web design. I m now interesting in google material design. My question is which hosting site allows to upload the own made html & css code ?

Comment: There are many of them! Try using Google to look for free web hosting.

Comment: Yes, I found many free hosting like zoho but they only allow the design which r using with their tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comparison on Wikipedia shows which ones allow custom HTML and CSS, amongst many other things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_web_hosting_services. At the moment the ones that meet this criteria are:

- Altervista
- Angelfire
- Blogger
- Google Sites
- Jimdo
- NeoCities

Comment: Thank you very much for your info :) it helped me

Comment: @KyawKyaw Glad to help. Would you please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question? Thanks.